# can't install PHPUnit through pear

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing PHPUnit via PEAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006626/installing-phpunit-via-pear)

the install instructions for phpunit are running this:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

the first one goes okay , on the second I get an error:

```
phpunit/PHPUnit requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.8.1), installed version is 1.7.2
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use package "pear/Image_GraphViz" (version >= 1.2.1)
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use package "pear/Log"
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use PHP extension "xdebug" (version >= 2.0.5)
No valid packages found
install failed
```

I just installed pear using both the latest go-pear.phar version from php.net(php 5.3.0)
also tried running `php go-pear.php` as pear website says.

running `pear -V` gives me version 1.7.2 , when I run `pear upgrade PEAR` it says my version is newer than the current noe which is 1.9.0, if ran `pear upgrade -f PEAR` to force an upgrade, it downloads the files and installs successfully but I still have version 1.7.2 and cannot install phpunit.

I am running windows vista, php 5.3.0

Answer (score 12):

Try type in console:

```
pear upgrade pear
```

Comment: Ah ha!  This command is strangely missing form the PEAR install guide.

Answer (score 7):

I found my solution ('cweiske' at irc.efnet.nl #pear) -

1. I removed my pear folder which resided in:

   `C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\bin`
2. Set php `include_path` to:

   `C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\bin\pear`
3. Got `go-pear.php` from:

   > http://pear.php.net/go-pear

   Save file as `go-pear.php`, I saved to `C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\bin`
4. Run `php go-pear.php` set PHP Code dir to same as `include_path`

   `C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\bin\pear`

and everything works

I am running 1.9.0.

Answer (score 2):

If you have problems with the upgrade or the install process, you can use:

```
peardev upgrade PEAR
peardev channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
peardev install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

It worked for me; I have Windows 7 64x + WAMP.