# Installing PHPUnit via PEAR

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

I have problems installing **PHPUnit 3.4.6** via **PEAR 1.9.0**. After I discover channel **pear.phpunit.de** and try to use one of following commands:

> pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
>
> pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
>
> pear install --onlyreqdeps phpunit/PHPUnit

it fails, giving me following error:

> No releases available for package
>   "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
>
> install failed

I found several threads from people with the same problem, but upgrading PEAR to the newest version usually worked for them. Also there seems to be close to no tutorials for installing PHPUnit for Windows.

**EDIT:**

I've also tried to change prefered_state to beta; didn't help.

I've also tried to get list of all available packages:

> pear remote-list -c phpunit

It gives me another error:

> Cannot download non-http URL  "/c/categories.xml"

Comment: What's the result of `pear remote-list -c phpunit` ?

Comment: Cannot download non-http URL "/c/categories.xml"

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday, and solved it by updating the channels

```
pear clear-cache
pear update-channels
```

before trying to install phpUnit.

Comment: This solved a similar issue I had installing phpunit 3.5.  Thanks.

Comment: This + cell's idea of `pear clear-cache` is what worked for me. +1 to each of you!!!

Comment: Can someone please put this clear-cache bold on the frontpage op stack overflow! After two hours I was about to throw away my laptop until I read this. Thanks dude!!

Answer (score 158):

I had the same problem, try:

```
pear clear-cache
```

Answer (score 12):

It simply installs me when I type:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear install --onlyreqdeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Maybe there is a problem with the versions, you may set the **preferred_state** of the pear packages to different than **stable**:

```
pear config-set preferred_state beta
```

Answer (score 12):

Please follow these steps:

  1.
  `pear config-set auto_discover 1`

  2.
  `pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit`
  -> here I got: installation failed.

  3. Try:
  `pear clear-cache`
  -> executed successfully

  4.
  `pear update-channels`
  -> executed successfully

  5.
  `pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit`
  -> successfully executed.

Comment: It works. before I had problem with Warning: require_once(Symfony/Component/Yaml/autoloader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Autoload.php on line 69. Using pear config-set auto_discover 1 I can install PHPUnit. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. this worked for me:

```
sudo pear clear-cache
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Comment: Had the same problem as Ondrej (but without the categories.xml error) and this worked a treat!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

What is the full error message output?  It failed for me until I installed using the `--alldeps` option and ran `pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com`

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
sudo pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Comment: can you edit your original post with the full error message you get when running `sudo pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit` ?

Comment: Ok, edited original post. I cannot (or not sure how to) use "sudo" (I'm a Windows user), but I'm administrator, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since 2014-12-31 PEAR Installer was no longer the only installation method for PHPUnit
See here : https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method

Answer (score 2):

I tried

```
pear update-channels
```

as suggested by Davide above, but that gave me the error

```
Channel pear.php.net does not support xml-rpc method channel.listAll
```

For some reason, it worked when I ran

```
pear channel-update pear.phpunit.de
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to also discover the ezcomponents channel using `pear channel-discover components.ez.no`

In total:

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
sudo pear channel-discover components.ez.no
sudo pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

You can have a quick sanity check is to run phpunit from the CLI and see if the command is recognized.

**UPDATE**

Seems they've moved symfony, I just did a fresh install today, here's the new channel

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem with phpunit instalation. Try using [Synaptic package manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) for PHPUnit instalation.

```
sudo pear install pear # upgrade pear first

#install php unit with synaptic manager

phpunit --version # get version of phpunit
```

Answer (score 1):

I had struggled for ages with getting ZEND etc to work on XAMPP on Windows Vista. For reference, this is how I solved it: -

Couldn't update PEAR then I realised it's default path setting were wrong, I correct this guide...

http://david-franklin.net/programming/installing-pear-phpunit-on-windows/

Then I managed to get PHPUNIT installed with the `pear clear_cache` command thanks to this thread then ran "pear install phpunit/PHPunit".

I hope what I wrote above will serve as a quick code for those in a similar predicament (it took me 2 whole days to get it working!!!)

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with not having a required dependency YAML, so got a warning each time.

Try
 `pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
   pear install pear.symfony.com/Yaml`

then run the download again

```
pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all xampp should be installed to **C:\xampp**

Open a command prompt and go to **C:\xampp\php**

Type the following commands in to the cmd

`pear update-channels`" (updates channel definitions)

`pear upgrade` (upgrades all existing packages and pear)

`pear channel-discover components.ez.no` (this is needed for PHPUnit)

`pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com` (also needed by PHPUnit)

`pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de` (This IS phpunit)

`pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit` (installs PHPUnit and all dependencies)