# Windows Installing PHPUnit via PEAR - Installing PHPUnit via PEAR

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

When I run:

```
peardev install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

I get the following:

```
No releases available for package "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
install failed
```

I have run the following:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
Channel "pear.phpunit.de" is already initialized
```

and

```
pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
No releases available for package "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
install failed
```

and

```
pear remote-list -c phpunit
CHANNEL PHPUNIT AVAILABLE PACKAGES:
===================================
PACKAGE            VERSION
DbUnit             1.0.2
File_Iterator      1.2.6
Object_Freezer     1.0.0
PHPUnit            3.5.14
PHPUnit_MockObject 1.0.9
PHPUnit_Selenium   1.0.3
PHP_CodeBrowser    1.0.0
PHP_CodeCoverage   1.0.4
PHP_Timer          1.0.0
PHP_TokenStream    1.0.1
Text_Template      1.1.0
bytekit            1.1.1
phpUnderControl    0.5.0
phpcpd             1.3.2
phpdcd             0.9.2
phploc             1.6.1
ppw                1.0.4
test_helpers       1.1.0
```

and

```
pear upgrade pear
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/pear"
upgrade failed
```

Please help I am tearing my hair out here.

**UPDATED**

```
C:\Program Files\PHP>pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
Channel "pear.phpunit.de" is already initialized

C:\Program Files\PHP>pear channel-discover components.ez.no
Channel "components.ez.no" is already initialized

C:\Program Files\PHP>pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
Channel "pear.symfony-project.com" is already initialized

C:\Program Files\PHP>pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
No releases available for package "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
install failed
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
C:\Program Files\PHP>pear update-channels
Updating channel "components.ez.no"
Channel "components.ez.no" is up to date
Updating channel "doc.php.net"
Channel "doc.php.net" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.php.net"
Channel "pear.php.net" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.phpunit.de"
Channel "pear.phpunit.de" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.symfony-project.com"
Channel "pear.symfony-project.com" is up to date
Updating channel "pecl.php.net"
Channel "pecl.php.net" is up to date
```

**Update 3**

ran

```
C:\Program Files\PHP>pear clear-cache
reading directory C:\Users\stephen\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\cache
136 cache entries cleared

C:\Program Files\PHP>pear install -a -f phpunit/PHPUnit
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use PHP extension "dbus"
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage can optionally use PHP extension "xdebug" (version >= 2
.0.5)
downloading PHPUnit-3.5.14.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-3.5.14.tgz (118,697 bytes)
..........................done: 118,697 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "C:\Program Files\PHP\tmp\PHPUnit-3.
5.14.tgz" Unable to create directory 'C:/Program/tmpF4D2.tmp'
Unable to create path for C:/Program/tmpF4D2.tmp/package.xml
Download of "phpunit/PHPUnit" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "phpunit/PHPUnit"
downloading DbUnit-1.0.2.tgz ...
Starting to download DbUnit-1.0.2.tgz (39,231 bytes)
...done: 39,231 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "C:\Program Files\PHP\tmp\DbUnit-1.0
.2.tgz" Unable to create directory 'C:/Program/tmpF64A.tmp'
Unable to create path for C:/Program/tmpF64A.tmp/package.xml
Download of "phpunit/DbUnit" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "phpunit/DbUnit"
downloading File_Iterator-1.2.6.tgz ...
Starting to download File_Iterator-1.2.6.tgz (3,439 bytes)
...done: 3,439 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "C:\Program Files\PHP\tmp\File_Itera
tor-1.2.6.tgz" Unable to create directory 'C:/Program/tmpF6E7.tmp'
Unable to create path for C:/Program/tmpF6E7.tmp/package.xml
Download of "phpunit/File_Iterator" succeeded, but it is not a valid package arc
hive
Error: cannot download "phpunit/File_Iterator"
downloading PHP_CodeCoverage-1.0.4.tgz ...
Starting to download PHP_CodeCoverage-1.0.4.tgz (115,029 bytes)
...done: 115,029 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "C:\Program Files\PHP\tmp\PHP_CodeCo
verage-1.0.4.tgz" Unable to create directory 'C:/Program/tmpF83F.tmp'
Unable to create path for C:/Program/tmpF83F.tmp/package.xml
Download of "phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage" succeeded, but it is not a valid package
archive
Error: cannot download "phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage"
downloading PHPUnit_MockObject-1.0.9.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit_MockObject-1.0.9.tgz (18,414 bytes)
...done: 18,414 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "C:\Program Files\PHP\tmp\PHPUnit_Mo
ckObject-1.0.9.tgz" Unable to create directory 'C:/Program/tmpF939.tmp'
Unable to create path for C:/Program/tmpF939.tmp/package.xml
Download of "phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject" succeeded, but it is not a valid packag
e archive
Error: cannot download "phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject"
downloading PHPUnit_Selenium-1.0.3.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit_Selenium-1.0.3.tgz (16,587 bytes)
...done: 16,587 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "C:\Program Files\PHP\tmp\PHPUnit_Se
lenium-1.0.3.tgz" Unable to create directory 'C:/Program/tmpF9F6.tmp'
Unable to create path for C:/Program/tmpF9F6.tmp/package.xml
Download of "phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium" succeeded, but it is not a valid package
archive
Error: cannot download "phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium"
downloading YAML-1.0.5.tgz ...
Starting to download YAML-1.0.5.tgz (9,966 bytes)
...done: 9,966 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "C:\Program Files\PHP\tmp\YAML-1.0.5
.tgz" Unable to create directory 'C:/Program/tmpFA83.tmp'
Unable to create path for C:/Program/tmpFA83.tmp/package.xml
Download of "symfony/YAML" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "symfony/YAML"
downloading PHP_TokenStream-1.0.1.tgz ...
Starting to download PHP_TokenStream-1.0.1.tgz (7,250 bytes)
...done: 7,250 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "C:\Program Files\PHP\tmp\PHP_TokenS
tream-1.0.1.tgz" Unable to create directory 'C:/Program/tmpFB10.tmp'
Unable to create path for C:/Program/tmpFB10.tmp/package.xml
Download of "phpunit/PHP_TokenStream" succeeded, but it is not a valid package a
rchive
Error: cannot download "phpunit/PHP_TokenStream"
downloading ConsoleTools-1.6.1.tgz ...
Starting to download ConsoleTools-1.6.1.tgz (869,994 bytes)
...done: 869,994 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "C:\Program Files\PHP\tmp\ConsoleToo
ls-1.6.1.tgz" Unable to create directory 'C:/Program/tmp9D.tmp'
Unable to create path for C:/Program/tmp9D.tmp/package.xml
Download of "ezc/ConsoleTools" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "ezc/ConsoleTools"
downloading Base-1.8.tgz ...
Starting to download Base-1.8.tgz (236,357 bytes)
...done: 236,357 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "C:\Program Files\PHP\tmp\Base-1.8.t
gz" Unable to create directory 'C:/Program/tmp36C.tmp'
Unable to create path for C:/Program/tmp36C.tmp/package.xml
Download of "ezc/Base" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "ezc/Base"
Download failed
install failed
```

**Update 4**

Installed PHP at c:\PHP

Ran the above steps and I now get:

```
C:\PHP>peardev install phpunit/PHPUnit
phpunit/PHPUnit requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.2), installed version is
 1.9.0
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use PHP extension "dbus"
phpunit/DbUnit requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.2), installed version is
1.9.0
phpunit/File_Iterator requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.2), installed vers
ion is 1.9.0
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed v
ersion is 1.9.0
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires package "phpunit/File_Iterator" (version >= 1.
2.2)
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage can optionally use PHP extension "xdebug" (version >= 2
.0.5)
phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.2), installed
 version is 1.9.0
phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.2), installed v
ersion is 1.9.0
phpunit/PHP_TokenStream requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed ve
rsion is 1.9.0
No valid packages found
install failed

C:\PHP>pear upgrade pear
pear/pear is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.9.3
upgrade failed
```

**Update 5**

```
C:\PHP>pear upgrade pear
pear/pear is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.9.3
upgrade failed

C:\PHP>pear -V
PEAR Version: 1.9.0
PHP Version: 5.2.17
Zend Engine Version: 2.2.0
```

Pear upgrade pear thinks I am 1.9.3 but pear says it is version 1.9.0

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I'm a really newbie but hope to be of any help.

I just succeeded installing PHPUnit a moment ago.

My env. is Wamp2.1.

I don't know exactly how this works but it worked for me, so try this.

`pear clear-cache` then,

```
pear install -a -f phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Somewhere in the failing message, I saw something about cache so I used `clear-cache`.

It did some trick in installing process, I guess.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you this helped me with my massive issue, i was at the point in quitting on PHPUnit

Comment: @eric could you explain flags -a and -f? 10x

Comment: Worked like a charm. What a wast of time this pear is.

Comment: @DmitrijGolubev: -f = forces the command (eg. re-install on top of existing), -a = all dependencies are installed.

Answer (score 13):

From the [manual](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html) page

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear channel-discover components.ez.no
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com

pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Make sure you have the two extra channels that are required.

**Edit:**

Try following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006626/installing-phpunit-via-pear): `pear update-channels`

Comment: @Will try updating the channels

Comment: That solved my issue. I got 'unknown channel "phpunit" in "phpunit/PHPUnit"' without adding the pear.phpunit.de channel. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
could not extract the package.xml file from "C:\Program Files\PHP\tmp\YAML-1.0.5
.tgz" Unable to create directory 'C:/Program/tmpFA83.tmp'
Unable to create path for C:/Program/tmpFA83.tmp/package.xml
```

This is a bug in pear installer. It can't deal with the SPACE in your path and tries to read the wrong files. Installing your php in a folder without a space is the only 'fix' i know about :/

---

Update 5:

```
pear install --force --alldeps pear/pear
```

do all channel updates it asks for

```
pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

if asked for channel updates, do those and repeat

Answer (score 2):

if the `Pear` command didn't work try this:

First off I'm assuming xampp is installed to C:\xampp

1. Open a command prompt and go to C:\xampp\php
2. Type "pear update-channels" (updates channel definitions)
3. Type "pear upgrade" (upgrades all existing packages and pear)
4. Type "pear channel-discover components.ez.no" (this is needed for PHPUnit)
5. Type "pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com" (also needed by PHPUnit)
6. Type "pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de" (This IS phpunit)
7. Type "pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit" (installs PHPUnit and all dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

You have several PEAR versions installed and are executing the wrong one. See
[Pear on windows displaying different version numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277938/pear-on-windows-displaying-different-version-numbers/6343429#6343429) for how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you're running command prompt as administrator and follow this

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear channel-discover components.ez.no
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com

pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```