# Pear on windows displaying different version numbers

Tags: php, windows, windows-7, pear

```
C:\PHP>pear upgrade pear
pear/pear is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.9.3
upgrade failed

C:\PHP>pear -V
PEAR Version: 1.9.0
PHP Version: 5.2.17
Zend Engine Version: 2.2.0
```

As you can see pear is confused to what version it is running. How can I go about fixing this so that PEAR is running on 1.9.3?

**Update**

```
C:\PHP>pear upgrade -f pear
downloading PEAR-1.9.3.tgz ...
Starting to download PEAR-1.9.3.tgz (295,774 bytes)
.............................................................done: 295,774 bytes

upgrade ok: channel://pear.php.net/PEAR-1.9.3
PEAR: Optional feature webinstaller available (PEAR's web-based installer)
PEAR: Optional feature gtkinstaller available (PEAR's PHP-GTK-based installer)
PEAR: Optional feature gtk2installer available (PEAR's PHP-GTK2-based installer)

PEAR: To install optional features use "pear install pear/PEAR#featurename"

C:\PHP>pear -V
PEAR Version: 1.9.0
PHP Version: 5.2.17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled php and re-installed it again. All the problems then went away.

Answer (score 1):

> use pear upgrade -f pear

this will force to upgrade if the upgrade version is newer

to use the channel try giving this command

> pear upgrade --force pear

this will update the base pear

Comment: try installing it pear install --alldeps pear..see what message it gives you

Comment: also use pear upgrade without any parameters

Comment: C:\PHP>pear install --alldeps pear
pear/pear is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.9.3
install failed

Comment: well there you go it is installed use command pear version .. after pear update channels ..

Comment: PEAR Version: 1.9.0. It's installed but the version numbered return is wrong.

Comment: use this # pear channel-update pear.php.net hopefully it will overwrite the xml file

Answer (score 1):

Is `pear` really located in `C:\PHP` or just within your path? I'm thinking that for some reason, there are two PEAR installations.

Answer (score 1):

You have two pear installations and upgrade the second pear with the first pear command.

Do a

```
$ pear list pear
...
script /usr/bin/pear
```

This is the pear script you want to execute. You are executing another one. Delete the other one and [set your PATH variable](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php#installation.getting.windows) to contain the correct path.