# How can I remove completely PHPUnit using the PEAR Installer?

Tags: php, windows, selenium, phpunit, pear

I installed PHPUnit using the PEAR installer a few days ago (I also installed Selenium RC for testing in PHP purpose). Now I want to uninstall it (also delete all related folders and files)

I ran the following command:

```
pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
```

and the console displayed:

```
phpunit/PHPUnit not installed
```

I checked the PHPUnit folder, it was still there?

Was it uninstalled? I try to reinstall a new PHPUnit, but the console displayed:

```
No releases available for package "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
```

How can I reinstall it?

---

Here's the output of `pear list -c pear.phpunit.de`:

[image: pear list -c pear.phpunit.de]

Here's output of `pear list -c pear.phpunit.de`:

[image: pear list -c pear.phpunit.de]

Comment: What does `pear list -c pear.phpunit.de` show?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: You can see the image here http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7034/6640174409_a7d13f8ff8.jpg

Comment: Console's output is text. You could have just pasted it here. :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: sorry, the above picture is for the command: pear remote-list -c phpunit.

for the command: pear list -c pear.phpunit.de.  the picture is: http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7150/6640195767_4894dc7bd9.jpg

Comment: ok, here is the text: <br/>
>C:\>pear list -c pear.phpunit.de  <br/>
>INSTALLED PACKAGES, CHANNEL PEAR.PHPUNIT.DE:  <br/>
============================================  <br/>
PACKAGE            VERSION STATE  
File_Iterator      1.3.0   stable  
PHPUnit_MockObject 1.1.0   stable  
PHP_CodeCoverage   1.1.1   stable  
PHP_Timer          1.0.2   stable  
PHP_TokenStream    1.1.1   stable  
Text_Template      1.1.1   stable

Comment: Why is this suggest off-topic to *webmasters*?

Comment: I've updated the question for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I checked the PHPUnit folder, it was still there?

That might be because of sub-components (Extensions, Framework). However you must not be concerned about that.

To install the latest version, do the following two commands:

```
> pear config-set auto_discover 1
config-set succeeded

> pear upgrade
...
```

This will take some time, and will update all that is currently installed. As you have some extensions already available and the latest version of PHPUnit might require those, so update them to prevent failure in the next command:

```
> pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

This should now install it:

```
Did not download optional dependencies: phpunit/PHP_Invoker, use --alldeps to download automatically
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use package "phpunit/PHP_Invoker" (version >= 1.0.0)
downloading PHPUnit-3.6.7.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-3.6.7.tgz (118,349 bytes)
..........................done: 118,349 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.6.7
```

**Troubleshooting PEAR**

As you reported in comments, this did not work out. Probably pear is in a state that it does not know where top and bottom is. Time to force. First, clear the cache:

```
> pear clear-cache
reading directory C:\...\Temp\pear\cache
0 cache entries cleared
```

Then force channel updates:

```
> pear channel-update -f pear.php.net
Updating channel "pear.php.net"
Update of Channel "pear.php.net" succeeded

> pear channel-update -f pear.phpunit.de
Updating channel "pear.phpunit.de"
Update of Channel "pear.phpunit.de" succeeded
```

Then force the phpunit install:

```
> pear install -a -f phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Comment: I took your guide but at the second command (pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit) the console still displayed as the last time:
No releases available for package "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit" install failed

Comment: okay, that's borked. Edorian posted something for windows, let me search for that answer.

Comment: @LeoLerdorf: I extended the answer. A related question is [Windows Installing PHPUnit via PEAR - Installing PHPUnit via PEAR](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6272264/367456).

Comment: @zerkms: Which off all have you tried? If you want come to PHP chat and/or create a new question where you outline your issue.

Comment: @hakre: well, I've found that it also depends on php version (though it doesn't state it explicitly)

Comment: @zerkms: Well which PHP versions you talk about specifically?

Comment: @zerkms: Doesn't have PHP 5.3.2 known bugs? I mean I would not expect that to work actually.

Answer (score 6):

As Google referenced this question as "how to REMOVE it", it seems important to answer the question.

As root, use:

```
pear list -c phpunit | grep stable | awk '{print "phpunit/"$1}' | xargs pear uninstall
```

Found this answer [here](https://gist.github.com/jmathai/2927956)