# How to upgrade phpunit to new version?

Tags: php, phpunit

Current, I installed phpunit. i use OS win 10. I think i installed new version from https://phpunit.de/ (current version 5.6, beta 5.7). But when check version with command line, it version 3.7. 
[My version PHP Unit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j054.png)

i read these post: [How do I update phpunit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094452/how-do-i-update-phpunit). But i can't understand. Help me !!! :(

Answer (score 26):

Just download the latest version and replace the old one. It is provided from the phpunit homepage.

```
$ wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar

$ chmod +x phpunit.phar

$ sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

You are in the latest version. To check version you can use

```
$ phpunit --check-version
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem :)

Comment: This does not provide the latest version, today it gave me 6.4.2 however 6.4.3 (or more) is available elsewhere.

Comment: you can access to `https://phar.phpunit.de/`, it actually shows the latest updated. and I check on the author github https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/06b28548fd2b4a20c3cd6e247dc86331a7d4db13, now he is preparing to released. If u want unreleased version, u always can build yourselves.

Comment: The code `whereis phpunit` before `sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit` helps a lot

Answer (score 7):

If you have installed PHPUnit globally with the PHP Archive (PHAR) procedure, you can simply run:

```
phpunit --self-update
```

Note that:

> The openssl extension is required for using the --self-update feature
>   of the PHAR.

[More info in the doc](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.phar.windows).

Hope this help

Comment: This was deprecated in v5.7 and does not work in versions greater v6 anymore.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have PHPUnit 3.7 installed globally and on your PATH. Either replace your global `phpunit` with the PHAR you downloaded or explicitly execute the latter.

Comment: thank you answer my question. :D. But i think i will use version PHPUnit of composer. it simple and great !!

Answer (score 2):

There are two different things update and upgrade. If you type

> phpunit

it will show you all commands available. If you see in the end it shows

```
--self-update       Update PHPUnit to the latest version within the same
                    release series.

--self-upgrade      Upgrade PHPUnit to the latest version.
```

Try what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can download as per php version and install it as globally:

```
wget -O phpunit https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-7.phar

chmod +x phpunit
```

To check version you can use:

```
./phpunit --version
```

To set phpUnit as globally you can use:

```
sudo mv phpunit /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

To run and test phpunit you can use:

```
phpunit
```

PHPUnit 7.3.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.