# upgrade phpunit windows

Tags: phpunit

I want to install PHPUnit 3.7 on my windows server. I followed the various instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272264/windows-installing-phpunit-via-pear-installing-phpunit-via-pear) and ended up with PHPUnit 3.4.1. When I try to install it again using:

```
pear update channels
pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

I get:

```
phpunit/PHPUnit is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.4.15
install failed
```

I know that 3.4.15 is not the latest version... How can I convince PEAR that it should find an upgrade somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the --force (or -f) option on pear install:

`pear install -a -f phpunit/PHPUnit`

I was running into problems with PHPUnit until I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272264/windows-installing-phpunit-via-pear-installing-phpunit-via-pear/6273037#6273037)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pear upgrade-all
pear upgrade phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and succeeded.

```
pear upgrade --alldeps phpunit/phpunit
```

If the above doesn't work for you, try the below:

```
pear upgrade --alldeps --force phpunit/phpunit
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance cleared the cache?

```
pear clear-cache
```

and then update the channels, and install phpUnit.
If that fails, clear the cache, uninstall completly phpUnit, and then install it again.