# Installing with PEAR

Tags: installation, pear, blowfish

I have been trying to install blowfish with pear ( http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_Blowfish ). I used the command `pear install Crypt_Blowfish` and I got it installed, but I was having some issues with my include path for PEAR so it wasn't working. I reinstalled pear, and everything seemed well, but when I went to reinstall the package, I get this error.

```
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/Crypt_Blowfish"
install failed
```

Did I mess up my PEAR installer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after looking a bit, someone had the same problem with installing PHPUnit with PEAR.

[Windows Installing PHPUnit via PEAR - Installing PHPUnit via PEAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272264/windows-installing-phpunit-via-pear-installing-phpunit-via-pear?rq=1)

I had to clear the cache with `pear clear-cache`. After that it installed!