# PEAR - Package installation (XML_Query2XML)

Tags: php, installation, pear

I was trying to install XML_Query2XML package but I am getting below error (I tried to install without -o parameter too, but got same error)

```
C:\Users\devdiu>pear install -o XML_Query2XML
```

No releases available for package `pear.php.net/XML_Query2XML`
install failed

Then I tried to install with specific version (which is latest as on today)

```
C:\Users\devdiu>pear install -o XML_Query2XML-1.7.2
```

No releases available for package "pear.php.net/XML_Query2XML"
install failed

Does any one know the issue?

Comment: The same problem seems to have been described (and solved) here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006626/installing-phpunit-via-pear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already tried that too. I have no clue why its giving error. I have installed it 3 times before I started getting this error. I actually wanted to ask different question but I stuck up at this one now.

Alternate way

I am manually copying the files into PEAR folder, to avoid further wastage of time

SOLUTION:

I got the solution in the link Lukas reconmended and resolved using this command (there are multiple accepted solutions there)

shell>pear clear-cache