# Oil test raises uncaught exception

Tags: php, phpunit, pear, fuelphp

I'm wandering a jungle of "php oil test" command for few days.

I installed phpunit via pear in windows7.
After the installation, When I execute "php oil test" command, following error occurs.

> > php oil test
>
> Uncaught exception Oil\Exception: PHPUnit does not appear to be installed.

However, it looks phpunit is installed correctly because "phpunit --version" command works fine(refer following).

> >phpunit --version
>
> PHPUnit 4.0.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Of course, "pear list" command shows PHPUnit package.

> >pear list
>
> INSTALLED PACKAGES, CHANNEL PEAR.PHPUNIT.DE:
>
> PACKAGE                   VERSION STATE
> File_Iterator             1.2.3   stable
>
> PHPUnit                   4.0.14  stable
>
> PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator 1.2.1   stable
>
> PHP_CodeCoverage          1.0.2   stable
>
> PHP_Timer                 1.0.0   stable
>
> PHP_TokenStream           1.2.2   stable
>
> Text_Template             1.2.0   stable

I tried some way listed following page, but cannot still resolve.

[Installing PHPUnit via PEAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006626/installing-phpunit-via-pear)

Could anyone pl give some advice to run "php oil test" command w/o error?

Any advice is welcomed!!

---

add my code.

- /fuel/core/classes/testcase.php

> namespace Fuel\Core;
>
> class TestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase { }

- /fuel/app/tests/controller_testcase.php

> use Fuel\Core\Log;
>
> use Fuel\Core\DBUtil;
>
> use Fuel\Core\DB;
>
> use Fuel\Core\TestCase;
>
> use Fuel\Core\Config;
>
> use Fuel\Core\Request;
>
> class ControllerTestCase extends TestCase {
>
> public function setUp() {
>
> ..

php is installed C:\php and pear.bat & phpunit.bat are also there.
PHPUnit folder does not exist in C:\php\pear folder.

Comment: are you sure it is included in your path?

Comment: Thanks for the info. But phpunit has been included in my system 'path' env:-(  Do y have any other idea?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant is it included in you code, do you have phpunit_framework_testcase included in your code?

Comment: well.. I'm still in jungle.
It looks ./fule/core/TestCase class extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase class.
And my code extends the TestCase class. So I think there is no problem at this point.
However PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase class does not exist in my pc anywhere.
And PHPUnit/Autoload.php does not exist either. 
So I tried to reinstall phpunit via pear again, but "php oil test" command still does not work:-<
What do you think what is wrong?

Comment: Please update your question with your code

Comment: update question. Can you pl take a look at?

Comment: mamdouh, I finally resolved this issue. It looks fuelphp's version and phpunit's version is inconsistent. When i install phpunit 3.7.12 instead of 4.0.11, this problem disappeared. I appreciate your support. Thanks.

Comment: You can answer your question and accept it after two days. This might help someone else :-)

Answer (score 0):

Oil uses the configuration key "oil.phpunit.autoload_path" to find the location of PHPUnit autoloader, and if not defined, it uses "PHPUnit/Autoload.php", in combination with the defined PHP include paths.

It then attempts to include this file, and checks if the class "PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase" is available. If not, it bails out with the error message you see.

It has nothing to do with the PHPUnit binary, which is located using the defined path.

This simply means the location where PHPunit is installed is not in PHP's search paths, and no custom path is configured.